# What is the weakest scheme in common use for password hashing?

Tags: passwords, hash, password-cracking

Essentially, what's the next step up from plaintext password storage?  I suspect the answer is going to be MD5, but I'm not familiar with a broad enough variety of examples to be sure.

The reason that I ask is that I'm trying to determine an appropriate strength to shoot for when generating passphrases.  I know that a dedicated cracking rig like [this one](https://gist.github.com/epixoip/ace60d09981be09544fdd35005051505) can run MD5 hashes at around 300 billion per second, so I'm thinking a minimum of about 67 bits of entropy (~10 years to crack.)

Is it reasonable to treat MD5 as the lower limit for password hashing?

EDIT:  To clarify, I'm not trying to store passwords, and if I were I certainly wouldn't be using MD5.  I'm just trying to figure out what's the worst-case scenario I'm likely to run into as a user, so that I can set a reasonable minimum complexity for my passphrases.  Obviously the true worst case would be plaintext password storage, but in that case no amount of complexity will save me.

I'm pulling from a dictionary of 15 thousand words, which gives my passphrases an entropy of ~14 bits per word.  So a 5-word passphrase should get me up to about 70 bits of entropy, which should be enough to defend against most attacks even if the password is stored via MD5.

My question essentially boils down to "Is there some other commonly-used hashing algorithm, that's even faster than MD5, that I should be aware of?"  If there is, then I need to reconsider my passphrase strength.

Comment: outside of targeted attacks, nobody is going to waste cpu on more than 12-14 chars of password

Comment: There are many weak hashes, md5 is not the weakest. However it does not matter much, since even with MD5 password policies would be unreasonable. If you want to define your personal password length keep in mind that not all sites accept long passwords or will truncate them or do not hash at all. If you use unique passwords per site you don’t have to worry about brute forcing them anyway. 67bits in hex will be 17 characters which might be longer than some sites allow. Add some special chars and go for 16 length I would suggest.

Comment: @dandavis sure they will. They'll just use a dictionary attack rather than exhaustive search.

Comment: @forest: With the talk of rates, I presumed OP's phrase will not be found in a dictionary and must be brute-forced, was I too generous?

Comment: @dandavis A hybrid attack can take a smaller dictionary (even one small enough to fit in the L3 cache) and permute it, giving benefits of both dictionary attacks and exhaustive search. You can easily attack long passwords that way. Hybrid attacks are actually the most common.

Comment: @dandavis you are correct, I'm working with passphrases generated from a large dictionary (see edit for details.)  I'm operating on the assumption that an attacker has my dictionary and is basing their attacks on it.

Comment: 5 words from 15,000 taken at "300 billion per second" is 2531250000 seconds, aka 80 years, not 10. word length is basically irrelevant once total length is above a dozen chars or so, so don't over-focus on bits.

Comment: Right, but 4 words from 15,000 at the same rate is only a couple of days.  If I want to make the building blocks words instead of characters (for memorability) then 4 is too few, so 5 is the minimum for me.

Comment: if you're worried, use 1337 on your passphrase to make it physically uncrackable. Yes, there's plugins to address that with pass _words_, but it's hopeless against pass _phrases_. Even having to map one replacement, say `e>3`, doubles the crack time, while 2 replacements quadruples it, etc. if you look at [all the 1-char subs](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leet), that's 128 combos. This turns your 80 years into `80^128 years`; aka physically impossible as we know it (requires more energy/time than the universe offers).

Comment: @dandavis Using 1337 on a passphrase is silly unless the attacker does not use any rulesets on the dictionary. In fact, some of the most popular and most common rulesets simply turn everything in a dictionary into 1337.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your definition of "common," [DES with passwords truncated to 8 characters](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/302419/solaris-let-me-in-with-different-password-with-the-same-8-first-characters) (for which rainbow tables exist).

Comment: I doubt (maybe hope is a better word) this is really that common any more. Raw MD5/SHA-1/SHA-2 with or without a salt are probably a few orders of magnitude more common, although it's hard to get any realistic data here.